# Cocoa failed to load window nib file when nib is localized

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create and show new window in my simple Cocoa application:

```
myWindow = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow" owner:self];
[myWindow showWindow:self];
```

It's working well with basic nib file without localization, but as soon as I turn on localization for this specific nib file (using Xcode "localize" option available form file inspector), the application gives me this error when executing the code above:

> -[MyWindowController loadWindow]: failed to load window nib file 'AuthWindow'.

Should I change the way I'm initializing my window controller when using localized nibs? It fails only when nib containing a window is localized (with just one language - English), when there is no localization configured - the window is loaded and appears on the screen as it should. I can't find the right answer, I'm new to Cocoa on OSX, but have some experience with CocoaTouch and developing for iOS.

Comment: I think when you localize a file Xcode creates an new folder and puts each files for a specific language in its correspondenting folder. After that your file path `MyWindow` is not valid anymore because it was moved (or copied) to a subdirectory. Unfortunately I am on holiday and can't provide you an answer. But Perhaps that gives you a point to start investigating ;)

Comment: @HAS yeah, I know about this. Everything seems to be correct when it comes to nib path, the en.lproj folder is created and localized nib is moved to that folder. I can open and edit nib in Xcode without a problem. I though that when I call initWithWindowNibName it should choose proper path for localized nib for current(?) language. I can't find any hint about loading localized nibs, so I assume that this should be done exactly the same way like for non-localized nibs, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I restarted Xcode and the error went away...

I don't know... but whatever...

Comment: clean the project(command + shift + k) and quit xcode (command + q) and relaunch xcode. :D

Answer (score 6):

`initWithWindowNibName:` *can* locate a **.nib** file in a localization directory such as `en.lproj/`. The problem is, sometimes Xcode forgets to compile a **.xib** file (an Interface Builder file in XML format, which you usually play with) into a **.nib** file, or a binary format - especially when the .xib file is just localized by clicking "Localized..." button.

If you open `$build_dir/Your.app/Contents/Resources/$locale.lproj` you will find some xibs only copied from the source directory.

Relaunching Xcode will resolve the situation, while I'm not sure what the cause is and why relaunching does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but I found a different solution than those above. In the nib in question, go to the identity panel and make sure the nib's target membership is checked.

[image]

Comment: `Targets` > `Build Settings` >
`Copy Bundle Resources` and add the xib is another way to do the same thing. I had this problem when integrating a xib file into a project that was previously referring to a xib file in another project.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like this.  What solved it for me was to make a backup copy of the xib file, delete it from xcode, restart xcode, then add it back.  Go figure...